# Several groups can have the same groupID?

Tags: aix, group

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # grep 300 /etc/group
ipsec:!:300:admgrp
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

?? Several groups (ipsec/admgrp) can have the same groupID (300)?? how can this be? /AIX 6.1/

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of the last field? On GNU/Linux, the last field in /etc/group is the *list of group members*. Are you sure that's not the case here, and `admgrp` just happens to be a somewhat inappropriately named user account? Try `grep admgrp /etc/passwd` and see what comes back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, several groups can have the same gid (though it's probably only useful when groups are given passwords), several users can have the same uid, but your line above says that the `admgrp` **user** is member of the `ipsec` group. You'd need:

```
ipset:!:300:
admgrp:!:300:
```

To have two groups with the same gid.